# Windows 10 screen garbage, do not know what else to try

Tags: windows, boot, reinstall

I have a the following problem with my laptop. Suddenly, one morning I went to start it and when it gets to the logon screen, the screen just shows random horizontal lines, totally indecipherable. But I can still log in, and shut it down, by just using key combinations, I assumed it was a hardware problem, but wait...
... I can still see the BIOS screen fine, I can still get to recovery mode, that is also fine. I even can boot into a recovery USB (Hirens), screen still totally fine. So I assume now it is not a hardware problem now but windows. I tried with an external monitor, no change.

Tried rolling back windows to earlier version, but only managed to uninstall last "quality update" no joy.
Then I tried to reset windows, twice, both times, screen works fine, but then at some point during install it just prints the weird lines on the screen again.
I tried removing one ram stick at a time, either way I still get the same problem when I restart.

Other info:

1. the screen garbage looks like the horizontal lines are out of sync, I can see the mouse moving, but it spread out in tiny lines all over the screen.
2. Normally I actually only get black screen, the only way to see the garbage is to plug in the external monitor cable, otherwise the laptop screen stays black. Nothing ever shows on the external.
3. Acer aspire E 15 (E 571 32nu)

Next things I am going to try are:
installing ubuntu or similar, if that works then I will stick with that, really I only need this laptop for Teams, VPN and remote desktop. OR
Maybe the windows reset was the wrong method, and it is just reinstalling the same broken/incompatible drivers. Could someone point me in the direction of a how-to, that lets me install earlier version of windows (without losing my licence).

Comment: We've seen similar issues a few times recently here - but no-one has ever reported back. If it's not actually a hardware issue, then I'd suspect the Intel graphics drivers. Safe boot, Hirens etc will not load the Intel but limp along using simpler built-in drivers. See https://downloadcenter.intel.com & get both the latest & something a few months old, see if it's just one build. Your chipset should be HD 4400 series.

Comment: Then I tried to reset windows, twice, both times, screen works fine, but then at some point during install it just prints the weird lines on the screen again. - not know much but my experience says that is a driver issue . you already tried many things except one !! get the latest iso and create bootable usb, format the drive and do a clean reinstall ; and afraid of losing license then see this - https://superuser.com/questions/947232/how-to-reinstall-windows-10-on-new-hard-disk and https://superuser.com/questions/1327650/w%C3%ACndows-10-full-format-without-losing-license

Comment: Update BIOS, and Chipset (affects Video) and Video drivers. Use the computer manufacturer's driver update app.   You asked  "...that lets me install earlier version of windows (without losing my license)?"   <-- you can install any version of Windows (keeping Home, Pro, etc) without losing your license but Windows may update it anyway.

Comment: Update: last windows iso had same problem, so I went two back to an iso from 2019, totally wiped drive. Installed from usb without letting it go on the internet, now it works and I can see my desktop again. Now just to see how I can force it to not update any more. Plus, it is very strange, the ultra basic graphics drivers from 2006 work, but even the 2015 driver kicks up errors. I assume that there is some part of the hardware that is broken/failing and that the basic driver does not use this component or uses is only lightly. Trying Linux now.